# Sencha Native Packaging with android

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Following is my configuration file (packager.json)

```
{
"applicationName":"Sencha",
"applicationId":"Sencha",
"iconName":"icon.png",
"versionString":"1.0",
"outputPath":"D:/wamp/www/sencha/mvc/",
"inputPath":"C:/wamp/www/sencha",
"webAppPath":"C:/wamp/www/sencha",
"androidAPILevel":"15",
"configuration":"Debug",
"platform":"AndroidEmulator",
"deviceType":"Universal",
"certificatePath":"debug.keystore",
"certificateAlias":"androiddebugkey",
"sdkPath":"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk",
"orientations": [
    "portrait",
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight",
    "portraitUpsideDown"
]
}
```

I also have created certificate for debug mode.

Following is the command I am using to generate certificate file

```
keytool.exe -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Then,

```
D:\wamp\www\sencha>sencha package run packager.json
```

command gave no error.
This command is suppose to generate .apk file, right ?? but nothing happened ?

What could have caused this ??

Answer (score 1):

Seems like backslashes in android-sdk path might be causing the problem.

Change `"sdkPath":"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk",` 
to `"sdkPath":"C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk",`.

Also try `sencha package build <packager json filename>` instead of `sencha package run <packager json filename>` as run command expects a running emulator.

For me it also required "certificatePassword" as one of the entries in the packager json file. Kindly get back to me if there are further complications.

Answer (score 0):

Have same issues:

```
Sencha : Android Native Build - ERROR 17: Unable to load PKCS12 identity
```

To build an Android Native app, 
        I referred Sencha Doc (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/...native_android)

```
    Step1:
    I created an Android Certificate using following command
    keytool -genkey -v -keystore athena.keystore -alias athena -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

    Step 2:
    Under Sencha-touch2-SDK directory, to build a apk file, I run following command:
    sencha app build native 

    with this I get following error: 
    ERROR 17: Unable to load PKCS12 identity from "/path/to/certificate.file"Failed to package application*



    Its not clear to me,
     if I need to user command jarsigner as follows:

    jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore athena.keystore athenamobile.apk athena

    ( when I tried above command, I get message: jarsigner: unable to open jar file: athenamobile.apk)


    Here is my android.json:        
    { 
    "applicationName":"AthenaMobile",
    "applicationId":"com.mycompany.AthenaMobile",
    "versionString":"1.0",
    "versionCode":"1",
    "iconName":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
    "inputPath":"C:/sencha-touch-2.0.1.1/AthenaMobile",
    "outputPath":"C:/sencha-touch-2.0.1.1/AthenaBuild",
    "configuration":"Release",
    "platform":"Android",
    "deviceType":"Universal",
    "certificatePath":"c:/athena.keystore",
    "certificatePassword":"athena", 
    "certificateAlias":"athena",
    "sdkPath":"c:/android-sdk-windows",
    "androidAPILevel":"16",
    "orientations": [
    "portrait",
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight",
    "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
    }


    Please note that,
    I did try command "sencha package run android.json" (as per doc),
    and hit with following errors:**

    Added file C:\sencha-touch-2.0.1.1\AthenaBuild\proguard-project.txt
    Buildfile: C:\sencha-touch-2.0.1.1\AthenaBuild\build.xml


    -set-mode-check:


    -set-release-mode:
    jarsigner: unable to open jar file: C:\sencha-touch-2.0.1.1\AthenaBuild\\
    enaMobile-release-unsigned.apk
    ""c:\android-sdk-windows\tools\android" create project --target android-1
    e AthenaMobile --activity STActivity --path "C:\sencha-touch-2.0.1.1\Athe
    \/" --package com.mycompany.AthenaMobile"
    Could not sign application with error: 1
    Failed to package application
    [ERROR]
    BUILD FAILED
    C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:1070: com.sun.org.apache.xerce
    nal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-
    nce.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidB
    8Reader.java:684)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF
```